# VueJS and Axios handle errors properly

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, axios

I am trying to raise an error during the login ... but weird thing is -> it does not work as I would expect it to ...

I am having this simple auth.service.js

```
class AuthService {
  async login(params) {
    try {
      const user = (await axios.post('/authentication', { ...params })).data;          
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

The "err" has the full axios error object (as shown below)

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 401",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=430fef65:1124:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=430fef65:1335:7)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "baseURL": "http://localhost:3030",
        "method": "post",
        "url": "/authentication",
        "data": "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"admin\",\"strategy\":\"local\"}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 401
}
```

what is weird is, that when I use that in my login method .. I am getting just the name and message values ... nothing else :(

```
 methods: {
    async login() {
        const payload = { username: this.username, password: this.password, strategy: 'local' };
        AuthService.login(payload)
          .then(() => {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
            this.loading = false;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error); // THIS DOES NOT SHOW THE ENTIRE OBJECT WITH ALL KEYS
            this.loading = false;
          });
    },
```

any idea why?

Comment: `new Error` accepts string message, it can't process an object according to your expectations. Is there something wrong with `throw err`?

Comment: such a lame mistake ... thx :)